# Extracting lines from text in expect bash

Tags: bash, expect

I have the following output in my expect script:

```
mydomain.com mail is handled by 30 pglegal-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com.
mydomain.com mail is handled by 10 mx1.myserver.com.
mydomain.com mail is handled by 20 mx2.myserver.com.
```

I want to extract the priority 10 mx server (mx1.myserver.com)

But I'm using expect like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

... script goes here
```

How would I go about extracting the mx server?

As stated in comments, I'm using expect due to it's easy application with telnet to communicate with a mail server.

I've got this regex for what I think the priority 10 mail server value:

```
(?<=10 )(.*)(.)
```

But I'm not sure how to apply to script.

Comment: Why are you using expect? Why not bash? Why not do it with `awk`.

Comment: Good question. I'm using expect so I can use telnet.

Comment: So split it in two files. First - bash - for optaining the server address and running `./expect the script serveraddress`, then `the script` which does the telnet/expect work. Or do it in bash. It's easier to put expect inside a bash script, then otherwise.

Comment: That sounds good. This is my first bash script, have you got any examples of how to deal with calling a script from another script, and getting the values from stdout, etc?

Comment: `yourExpectCommand | sed -nE 's/^.*is handled by 10 (.*)\.$/\1/p'` should work nicely; here's a test where I replace your `expect` command by an `echo` of its expected output : https://ideone.com/mt5lQm

Comment: It should be pretty straightforward, however you need to show more of your expect code that generates that output.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.